# Alternate background color for rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on alternate background color and facing some challenges. I want to set alternate background color only to ODD rows by CSS or JavaScript/jQuery. In fiddle, I have intentionally hided the EVEN rows, because the requirement is the same. I was trying to achieve it using jQuery but not able to proceed further. And please guys don't suggest me to replace the TABLE with DIV. Unfortunately I am working on old markup(Intranet website). Help/guidance would be appreciated for existing HTML markup.

```
    if($('table tr').hasClass('odd')){
        $(this).find('td :first-child').css('background','yellow');
    }
```

**EDIT**

For all blue backgrounds.. I want to change those background color as an alternate either odd or even? I think it's clear now?

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dgJ3/6)

Comment: As you can see by the different answers, your question is ambiguous... if my guess to what you want is correct, and the classes "odd" and "even" really alternate as neatly as in your example, you can use `nth-of-type(4n+1)`. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dgJ3/4/).

Comment: thank you for the solution. however for even rows- display is set to none and it's happening dynamically, i can't control that. I have edited the requirement.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve. Your css is making the tr.odd blue and tr.even red and hidden. What are you trying to make yellow? The H2? And what else are you trying to do?

Comment: #Peter http://jsfiddle.net/5dgJ3/6/   can you see all blue backgrounds.. I want to change those background color as an alternate either odd or even? I think it's clear now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you dont have to use a Script for that.

look at the [CSS even/odd rule.](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd)

you can assign a background color to all even/odd `tr`.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dgJ3/2/)

just add this to your **CSS**, and lose the Script.

```
tr.odd tr:nth-child(even) /*or [odd] if you need*/
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

also, change your `background` rules to `background-color` if you're just going to use the color.

**Update:**

from your comments, I understood that you want only the odd tables of the odd class to be selected. (it was very unclear from the question)

so: see this [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/5dgJ3/7/)

```
tr.odd:nth-child(4n+1)
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I know it already, what you are suggesting. Would appreciate if you please go through my requirement.. thanks.

Comment: I've puted a fiddle for you.

Comment: Basically the requirement is for ODD td - I want the alternate(even) background color changed along with the content(table) which is coming inside the TD

Comment: So?? Write odd instead of even. Its also mentioned in the answer in the comment.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/5dgJ3/6 can you see all blue backgrounds.. I want to change those background color as an alternate either odd or even? I think it's clear now?

Comment: I think I finally understood what you want. check the updated answer. next time, try to explain yourself more clearly (with an image or something)

Answer (score 0):

If your odd table rows have the class "odd" already then you can just apply normal CSS to the class "odd".

If you need to change the first column's background color within the odd rows, you probably want to use `td:first-of-type` instead of first-child.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$('table tr:visible:odd').css('background','yellow');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dgJ3/1/)

In case even rows visibility isn't changes, ':visible' selector is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object:nth-child(even)` (or odd) for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/5dgJ3/3/

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar to this but i used a class to add the "odd" styles to it.

```
$(function() {
    $("table tr:odd").addClass("odd");
});
```

Might be a little simpler if you want to add more styles than the BG color.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand. You want every other tr.odd to have a different background color. Here's how to do it with jQuery (if you need to support older versions of IE):

```
$('tr.odd:even').css('background','yellow');
```

Comment: Basically the requirement is for ODD td - I want the alternate(even) background color changed along with the content(table) which is coming inside the TD

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably leave off the "odd" class as it serves limited semantic meaning and just have jQuery apply the class then have css do the styling.

**Option 1**

jQuery:

```
$('tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

CSS:

```
.odd {
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gyrostu/eY2WQ

**Option 2**

Pure CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

[W3C Web Style Sheets CSS tips & tricks](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr:odd", "#adminMessageId").css("background-color", "SkyBlue");

        $("input").focus(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#cccccc");
        });
        $("input").blur(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        });
```